# How to execute a function only if a mouseover listener is not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, listener, dom-events

In order to avoid a sort of flickering effect on the screen due to rollover effects on my page, I want to activate a function from `mouseOut` of a thumbnail only if a `mouseOver` state on a different thumbnail is not currently happening. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see if any your thumbnail elements have an `active` class that is added when a successful `mouseout` event fires. If any other thumbnail elements have this class then do nothing, if none are found then run your `mouseout` code:

```
$('.thumb-element').on('mouseout', function () {
    if ($('.thumb-element').filter('.active-mouseout').length == 0) {
        //there are no elements with both the `thumb-element` class and the `active-mouseout` class so you can do work here
        $(this).addClass('active-mouseout').animate({top : 'XXpx'}, 250, function () {

            //now we remove the `active-mouseout` class so another `mouseout` event can run
            $(this).removeClass('active-mouseout');
        });
    }
});
```

You can then remove the `active-mouseout` class when necessary, for instance if it requires an animation then you can remove this class in the callback for that animation.

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/zg5g7/

Comment: This is a great solution; I like how the elements themselves contain the logic needed to determine if any of the elements are animating.  An alternative is to use a variable to track when an animation is started.  There is no reason to use the alternative unless the cost of scanning the elements for a certain class becomes relevant (probably wouldn't be until it's in the thousands)

Comment: This can be optimized by caching the `$('.thumb-element')` selector whenever possible (if they are all in the DOM on `document.ready` then I would use that event).